# Finding most occurring value(cv::Vec3b) results seems to be wrong

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to find the value of the most occurring value through a for loop. I didn't use the sort function as `currentChar` and `mostChar` are `cv::Vec3b` values. The program is as shown:

```
for (int z = 0; z < temp.size(); z++)
{
    currentChar = temp[z];
    mostChar = temp[z];
    currentCount = 0;
    mostCount = 0;
    for (int i =0; i < temp.size(); i++)
    {
        cv::Vec3b c = temp[i];

        if (c == currentChar)
            currentCount++;

        if (currentCount > mostCount)
        {
            mostChar = currentChar;
            mostCount = currentCount;
        }
    }
}
std::cout << "most occurring values is" << mostChar << "with " << mostCount << " times!" << endl;
```

The results seem to be weird. I have tried for quite a bit already. Not sure if there is something wrong with my program flow. I am used to doing something like this, which works:

```
sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
int currentChar = temp[0];
int mostChar = temp[0];
int currentCount = 0;
int mostCount = 0;
for (int i =0; i <temp.size(); i++)
{
    int c = temp[i];
    if (c == currentChar)
        currentCount++;
    else
    {
        if (currentCount > mostCount)
        {
            mostChar = currentChar;
            mostCount = currentCount;
        }
        currentChar = c;
        currentCount = 1;
    }
}

std::cout << "most occurring values is" << mostChar << "with " << mostCount << " times!" << endl;
```

Now without the sort function and using for loops, my results seem to be weird. Any idea? I have tried:

```
if (c == currentChar)
    currentCount++;
else
{
    if ( currentCount > mostCount)
    {
            mostChar = currentChar;
        mostCount = currentCount;
    }
        currentChar = c;
        currentCount = 1;
    }
}
```

in the for loop method, and kept changing here and there, but the results still seem to be weird. Any idea. Been awhile since I played around with programming and is embarrassed at being stuck at something this simple, but I want to improve! So please help. What's wrong with the flow?

EDIT: Tried using operator, but results still doesn't seem to be right.

My code for operator:

```
struct //Compare : public std::binary_function<cv::Vec3b,cv::Vec3b,bool>
{
    bool operator()(cv::Vec3b &a, cv::Vec3b &b)
    {
         return std::tie(a[0], a[1], a[2]) < std::tie(b[0], b[1], b[2]); 
    }
}inOrder;
```

And I use it a parameter for the sort function.

```
sort(temp.begin(), temp.end(),inOrder);
```

However the result is still not desirable or rather don't seem to be right. Did I declare the operator wrongly? I got the idea from here, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort, under the custom function object.

Comment: BTW, the version with `std::sort` is better. (`O(n log n)` vs `O(n²)`).

Comment: @Jarod42, Yup. I agree, however, I can't use `std::sort` with `cv::Vec3b format`, which is multi-dimensional vector. Used to do that, now, when I can't use it, face this kind of problem :(

Comment: You may provide your own comparator if `operator < (const Vec3b&, const Vec3b&)` doesn't exist.

Comment: Just a quick question, I have created my `operator`, how do I use it together with sort? Thanks.

Comment: [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)`(temp.begin(), temp.end(), mycomparator)`. or if you do `operator < (const Vec3b&, const Vec3b&)`, the normal way `std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end())`.

Comment: So if I used operator, I edit the header file(operations.hpp right?)

Comment: You may declare/define it where you want (as other function). It may be local to your file if you want.

Comment: For your comparator function: No need to inherit from `binary_function`, argument should be `const` (as the method). Have you check that with `cv::Vec3b a, b;` `a == b` gives what you want ?

Comment: Note also that the expected value of float is generally misleading for the user (rounding, operation not associative as in mathematics...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mostChar` and `mostCount` are reset at each iteration, so `mostChar` will always be the last element.

Move

```
mostChar = temp[z]; // replace by temp[0]
mostCount = 0;
```

outside of the loop.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. Now wat they return is " [0],[0],[0]" occurred (number of times).

Comment: That was one of the first few I tried. That's why I am feeling super confused why it can't generate the right values:(

Comment: It seems to work (with `int`) : https://ideone.com/zDYn7U . Is `cv::Vec3b::operator ==` what do you expect ?

Comment: yup, it works with `int`. That's why I tried using the same method for `cv::Vec3b` What I want do is if `[55][66][45]` appears the most number of time, to show that value, along with the number of times it appeared. Similar to int, but it does not seem to work that way. I am trying to introduce my own comparator suggested by u in the comments. Never really done that before so it might take a while to figure it out. Hope that works.

Comment: Upvoted one for you. Can you just help me check though on one last thing. Is the way I introduce the operator wrong for finding the most occurring value (edited my post, with that problem.)